# Change method signature of App.xaml.cs to return async Task<bool>

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, async-await, task

Can I change the method signature of the inicialization method in App.xaml.cs?

I am trying to make the app wait till I download essencial data to load it to the next screen, but I got an error when I tried it using Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0.

This is the method. it is in App.xaml.cs and it is the method that executes when the app is launching.

Normal signature with async. I added the word async .

> ```
>     private async void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
>     {
>         Debug.WriteLine("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
>
>         Debug.WriteLine("App-> Launching -> salvar_JSON");
>         App.estaAtivo = true;
>         try
>         {
>             Debug.WriteLine("App-> Launching -> sevidorWeb-> salvarJSON // Tentativa");
>             await web.salvarJSON(ServidorWEB.URL_JSON_SLZ, ServidorWEB.ARQUIVO_JSON_SLZ);
>             await web.salvarJSON(ServidorWEB.URL_JSON_ITZ, ServidorWEB.ARQUIVO_JSON_ITZ);
>             await web.salvarJSON(ServidorWEB.URL_JSON_STI, ServidorWEB.ARQUIVO_JSON_STI);
>             await sleepObj.set_to_NENHUM();
>             App.HOJE = await tempo.getDiaSemana();
>             await tempo.iniciarRelogioInterno(web);
>
>         }
> ```

With the signature changed for what I want:

> ```
>   // Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
>         // This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
>         private async Task<bool> Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
>         {
>             Debug.WriteLine("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
>
>             Debug.WriteLine("App-> Launching -> salvar_JSON");
>             App.estaAtivo = true;
>             try
>             {
>                 Debug.WriteLine("App-> Launching -> sevidorWeb-> salvarJSON // Tentativa");
>                 await web.salvarJSON(ServidorWEB.URL_JSON_SLZ, ServidorWEB.ARQUIVO_JSON_SLZ);
>                 await web.salvarJSON(ServidorWEB.URL_JSON_ITZ, ServidorWEB.ARQUIVO_JSON_ITZ);
>                 await web.salvarJSON(ServidorWEB.URL_JSON_STI, ServidorWEB.ARQUIVO_JSON_STI);
>                 await sleepObj.set_to_NENHUM();
>                 App.HOJE = await tempo.getDiaSemana();
>                 await tempo.iniciarRelogioInterno(web);
>                 return true;
>             }
> ```

How can I do it?

The error is following:

[image]

Comment: You can do the download in Application_Lauching only if you call your methods synchronously, which would give awful UX (as mobile phones have unstable networks, so downloads can take a long while). Just redirect the user to a custom page with a "loading" message (a kind of splashscreen basically) and do the download at your leisure. Or even better, do the download directly from the page that needs it (using a progress indicator)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion of KooKiz.

But also you can still keep the function signature as it is and use Task.Run().Wait() mechanism.

You can put your async functions in the Run block and force the UI to wait it out.

Like I said, its not a good approach and would advice to show some loading screen and put your resource loading mechanism behind that.